# Is there an easy way to simulate events between WCF service and WCF client?

Tags: c#, wcf, events, callback, ipc

So I've achieved localhost WCF Named Pipes communication between client EXE and server EXE. I can call class methods on the server over localhost. So, it's like an IPC/RPC. However, if the server's class method takes a long time to execute, then it's best for me to throw that into a thread so that the server class method finishes and runs this thread in the background. Okay, fine, but then when the thread is finished its long task, I want to alert the client without having to use a timer on the client that would check that class method. A timer hitting a class method is a lot more inefficient than a raised event. It's like I need to raise an event on the client from the server. Is there an easy way to do this or to at least simulate it, without a lot of confusing work?

Comment: You could make your WCF methods [asynchonous](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2010/11/12/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-asyncawait/) then it's a simple matter of `async/await` or do away with WCF completely and use built-in async with `NamedPipeClientStream` (which is still `await` compatible).  Not to mention a speed boost in the latter when doing away with verbose XML SOAP encoding

Comment: @MickyD You were right on the async/await thing now that I have studied that and implemented a test that works. That allows me to almost simulate a callback on a long running task and with minimal lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This is an answer formulated from my comment to the OP's question

---

You could make your WCF methods [asynchonous](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2010/11/12/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-asyncawait/) then it's a simple matter of `async/await` or do away with WCF completely and use built-in async with `NamedPipeClientStream` (which is still await compatible). Not to mention a speed boost in the latter when doing away with verbose XML SOAP encoding

OP:

> @MickyD You were right on the async/await thing now that I have studied that and implemented a test that works. That allows me to almost simulate a callback on a long running task and with minimal lines of code

e.g.  to build upon the OP's answer but to use `async/await` correctly:

### Client code

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // <-- note async
{
    label1.Text = await client.GetDataAsync(textBox1.Text); // <-- note await. New method
}
```

Now you could be tempted to use `Task.Run` but doing so is bad because:

1. `Task.Run` is best suited for compute-bound operations which we aren't.
2. `Task.Run` will at the most use an expensive thread-pool thread

We're performing an I/O operation and as such can benefit from I/O Completion Ports and *"there is no thread"* philosphy of IOCP present in Task I/O bound operations.  As such when we make the server call via `GetDataAsync`, we don't waste a thread waiting for a result.

### WCF Server

Here we simulate a lengthy operation by waiting, but instead of using `Sleep` which isn't `Task`-aware, we use `Task.Delay` which is an awaitable operation.

```
Task<string> async GetDataAsync (string text)
{
    await Task.Delay (Timespan.FromSeconds(5));
    return text + " processed";
}
```

Comment: How come I can get this to work without having to implement the `Task<string> async GetDataAsync(string test)` in the WCF service EXE?

Comment: It looks like Microsoft automatically creates for you the `*Async(*)` class method. I created an `Example2()` and then did the Update Service Reference on the client, and then was able to call `Example2Async()` automatically.

Comment: @Volomike yes that's right.  You might want to take a peek at _[WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101)_ as it prevents the problem where client proxies don't agree with the actual service. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, let's say you have a button click in your UI that does a WCF synchronous method call on the WCF service, and that synchronous method takes a long time to run. Obviously, you don't want to block the UI from updating while that long running task executes. Naturally, you might be thinking about a callback. As in, you make the call to the server, and the class method on the server spawns a thread and runs that task, and when it's done, it returns back to the client a result via a callback.

To set that all up on WCF involves many complex, confusing, poorly documented steps, actually. But there's a much easier way, and it doesn't involve WCF code at all, and doesn't involve you changing anything on the WCF service, nor editing any WCF configurations. The trick is introduced in .NET 4.5 and greater. It's called `async` and `await`. Here is an example of a button click that calls a WCF service method that takes a long time to run and then returns the result when it's finished, and yet the GUI doesn't lock up and can handle other events.

1. First, to simulate a slow task, edit your WCF service project's shared class method and add this line in before the return result so that you can simulate a 5 second pause:

```
Thread.Sleep(5000); // requires using System.Threading;
```

In my case, I put that in my `GetData()` method.

2. Now switch to your WCF client project. You may have a button click handler that looks like this, as an example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string returnString = client.GetData(textBox1.Text));
  label1.Text = returnString;
}
```

So, switch that with three minor changes:

a. Add `using System.Threading.Tasks;`.

b. Change `private void...` to `private async void...` on your button click handler.

c. Utilize `await Task.Run(...)` with your slow method call.

Thus, the code would look like so:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Task.Run() requires "using System.Threading.Tasks;"
  string returnString = await Task.Run(() => client.GetData(textBox1.Text));
  label1.Text = returnString;
}
```

The end result is that when you click the button in the WCF client project, the GetData() class method is called on the WCF service project in a background thread, and, when finished, it comes back to that `await` statement and returns the result to the variable assignment. In my case, I clicked the button and nothing happened for 5 seconds -- the label with the result string didn't change. However, the GUI wasn't locked up -- I could drag the window around, type in other fields, click other form buttons, and so on. So, it's almost like a callback event handler, but not exactly. Still, it serves the same functionality and can be used in place of a callback event handler in most cases. And it involves far less code.